# What exactly is the yellow thing that plue has?

Tags: rave-master

In this picture off Plue from the Rave Master [wiki](http://ravemaster.wikia.com/wiki/Plue), it's stated to be a horn/nose. 
[image: plue]

But what exactly is that yellow thing? Is it a nose or a horn? If it's nose, can Plue smell with that?

Comment: why not both? he can smell and stab people with that

Comment: Judging by the position where the "yellow thing" is located it looks more like a nose. Horn's are located either on the forehead or on top of the head. Plue is not a fighting type, rather a pet type, so don't think it'll be using its "nose" for drilling into enemies.

Comment: I always thought Plue was inspired by a dog getting an ice cream cone stuck on its nose, hence the cold shakes & horn/nose referencing together but I could be entirely crazy so ignore this comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most site, even Rave wiki always refer it as a nose due to its position that like a nose. But actually it's not both, it looks like horn, and the position is more like nose but it's the weapon that only Plue has

[image]

Just like that picture says, even Hiro Mashima not sure what it is. (or he just didn't want to tell us)